# Is there a way to have a multi-module maven project list the group/artifact IDs of the artifacts it deploys?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am putting together generic scripts to support a CI pipelines for many different Maven projects (many of these are multi-module project).

I would like to write a Bash script that will catalog the group ID, artifact ID, and artifact (JAR/WAR) which are deployed by any given build. However, I am having a difficult time figuring out how to get this information in a fool-proof manner.

Does maven provide any support for retrieving this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `maven-deploy-plugin`'s log.

To get artifactId, use this line:

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ artifact-id ---
```

For other stuff:

```
[INFO] Uploaded: path-to-artifactory/group-id-path/artifact-name/path-to-jar-artifact/artifact.jar
```

`path-to-artifactory` remains constant in all cases. Since you also know `artifact-name`, you can get `group-id-path`. Then replace `/` or `\\` (whatever the file separator) is with `.`. For example, `com/company/something/group1` will give you the groupId as `com.company.something.group1`.

And you will also know the name of uploaded file and its location relative to the artifact's location as `path-to-jar-artifact`.